# How does this priority queue work?

Tags: java, priority-queue

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class QueueInts{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>();
    String expression = "(2+4)-8 * (3-1)";
    String symbols = "()+-*/% ";

    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
      if (!symbols.contains("" + expression.charAt(i)))           
          q.add((int)expression.charAt(i)-48);
      System.out.println(q);
    }

    System.out.println(q);
    while (q.size() > 0)      
        System.out.println(" " + q.remove());     
}
}
```

the output is []

```
[2]

[2]

[2, 4]

[2, 4]

[2, 4]

[2, 4, 8]

[2, 4, 8]

[2, 4, 8]

[2, 4, 8]

[2, 4, 8]

[2, 3, 8, 4]

[2, 3, 8, 4]

[1, 2, 8, 4, 3]

[1, 2, 8, 4, 3]

[1, 2, 8, 4, 3]

 1

 2

 3

 4

 8
```

I think I understand when its [2,4,8] however I don't understand after that. Could anyone tell me how this code is working?

Comment: What were you expecting exactly? What don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand the part in which the 3 gets put in front of the 8 and the 4 behind the 8.

Comment: Elements are removed in correct order, what does surprise you?

Comment: what i was asking is why does it go from q[1] = 4 and all the sudden q[3] = 4 and q[2] not bumped to q[3] instead of q[1] being bumped to q[3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()), the `PriorityQueue` inherits its `toString()` functionality from the `AbstractCollection`, which states that it prints out the elements of the collection as returned by the `iterator()` in brackets.

Looking at the `iterator()` method of the `PriorityQueue`,

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

So the output of your program does not have any meaning, until you print them out after you call `remove()`, in which case they're sorted according to their natural (numerical) order as expected.

Comment: Oh ok that answers my question completely thank you very much!!!! I thought there was a reason behind the particular order before the the printing.

Comment: Pleasure! Don't forget to upvote / accept if it was helpful ;)